# Fire Event from dynamically loaded XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I load an XAML file (page) on runtime in my WPF application:

```
<Frame x:Name="xamlNode"></Frame>
```

code behind:

```
FileStream s = new FileStream("Page1.xaml", FileMode.Open);  
xamlNode.Source = new Uri("Page1.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
xamlNode.NavigationUIVisibility = NavigationUIVisibility.Hidden;
s.Close();
```

First thing I find strange is that the Code is executed I run on Page1.xaml.cs. shouldn't be this XAML file be without any business logic? Neverteheless this is what I need.

But how can I raise an event in my parent WPF application from the Page1.xaml.cs e.g. on a button press?

The origin of my problem is: I need a user to design simple "pages" in VS and then load on runtime. But I need an event when user finished something on that pages.

Comment: This should be possible. Have you used a viemodel and used MVVM binding? Have you bound that viewmodel to the page's datacontext?

Comment: I have no viewmodel

Comment: Ok, so, in your use case the page has a button. Who will define what will happen when the user clicks that button? Is it defined in the application or on the page?

Comment: "shouldn't be this XAML file be without any business logic"? It depends on the developer. You should look into MVVM. It is *the* recommended pattern for developing XAML based UI applications. And from where and when do you want to raise an event to who?

Comment: I have  validation logic in the Page1.xaml.cs and want to raise the event on my main application when Page1 is valid.

Comment: I agree with @mm8, using a viewmodel an the appropriate pattern will simplify this case. If your goal is to build a modular application, I have heard good things about [prism](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/wpf/Modules.html)

Comment: "on my main application" means that you want your "main application" to be able to subscribe to and handle the event?

Comment: yes either this way or I think executing a function inside Page1.xaml.cs would also fit my needs

Comment: I don't think your cs file is loaded, but let me know if it does.

Comment: the code is executed. Not sure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frist, for your problem, you can handle any routed event raised by any visual descendants by using `UIElement.AddHandler` method. Assume you have registered a handler for `Frame.Loaded` event.

```
private void Frame_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((UIElement)sender).AddHandler(Buttion.ClickEvent, (RoutedEventHandler)((s, e1) =>
    {
        Button btn = (Button)e1.OriginalSource;
        if (btn.Name == "same kind of id")
        {
            // handle the event.
        }
    }));
}
```

And for the Page1.xaml code executed problem, if you compliled the xaml file, the code will executed because you specify the page as the `Source` of the `Frame`. I have to point out that the `FileStream` have nothing to do with loading Page1.xaml. In the other hand, if you use a loose xaml as the source of the frame, any code should not allowed for xaml. So please check your build action for Page1.xaml.